# SQL when parameter is null then get all

Tags: sql, parameters, case-when

I'm trying to one sql query

```
alter procedure [dbo].[sp_E_GetProducts]
@skip as INT = 0,
@take as INT = 999999,
@search as NVARCHAR(50) = '',
@urtkod as NVARCHAR(50) = ''
as
begin
; with MyTable as ( 
select sto_kod, sto_isim, sto_sat_cari_kod, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY sto_kod) as row from MikroDB_V14_AKCAY2010.dbo.STOKLAR where
(sto_isim like '%' + @search + '%' or sto_kod like '%' + @search + '%') and sto_sat_cari_kod <> '' and  @urtkod like '%' + sto_sat_cari_kod + '%'

)

select * from MyTable where row between @skip and @take
end
```

its working when i put parameters not null but when @urtkod is null i want take all table (it mean "and sto_sat_cari_kod <> '' and  @urtkod like '%' + sto_sat_cari_kod + '%'" will ignore), i research "case when" but it didn't work or i do it wrong.

Comment: Try wrapping your parameters with an ISNULL(). So, ISNULL(@urtkod,'') like '%' + sto_sat_cari_kod + '%'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
alter procedure [dbo].[sp_E_GetProducts]
@skip as INT = 0,
@take as INT = 999999,
@search as NVARCHAR(50) = '',
@urtkod as NVARCHAR(50) = ''
as
begin
    If (@urtkod is null)
    Begin
        ; with MyTable as ( 
        select sto_kod, sto_isim, sto_sat_cari_kod, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY sto_kod) as row from MikroDB_V14_AKCAY2010.dbo.STOKLAR where
        (sto_isim like '%' + @search + '%' or sto_kod like '%' + @search + '%') and sto_sat_cari_kod <> '' and  @urtkod like '%' + sto_sat_cari_kod + '%'

        )
    End
    Else
    Begin
        ; with MyTable as ( 
        select sto_kod, sto_isim, sto_sat_cari_kod, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY sto_kod) as row from MikroDB_V14_AKCAY2010.dbo.STOKLAR where
        (sto_isim like '%' + @search + '%' or sto_kod like '%' + @search + '%') and sto_sat_cari_kod <> '' --and  @urtkod like '%' + sto_sat_cari_kod + '%'

        )
    End
select * from MyTable where row between @skip and @take
end
```

Also you can check for `''`....

Comment: just now i did that before see, but its the best solution ? we can't do it on one query?

Answer (score 0):

Change the below section

```
and  @urtkod like '%' + sto_sat_cari_kod + '%'
```

to

```
and     (@urtkod like '%' + sto_sat_cari_kod + '%' OR @urtkod IS NULL)
```

Using SQL SERVER and [ISNULL](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx)

you could change it to

```
and     (ISNULL(@urtkod,'') like '%' + sto_sat_cari_kod + '%')
```

Also maybe have a look at [SQL NULL Functions](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp) for the different version between RDBMSs

Comment: its just making urtkod null to '' (empty) and when i set empty or null i just get empty sto_sat_cari_kod but i need all sto_sat_cari_kod

Comment: i want to just ignore last part and sto_sat_cari_kod <> '' and @urtkod like '%' + sto_sat_cari_kod + '%'" when urtkod is empty or null